# ffmpeg cover image for mp4 youtube

Tags: ffmpeg

when I upload the video to youtube the thumbnail is not shown it rather shows other parts of the video rather than my 55.png.

```
ffmpeg -i 55.mp4 -i 55.png -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -disposition:v:1 attached_pic sample_w_artwork.mp4
```

how do I add 55.png in the way so when I upload it to youtube it finds it as a thumbnail

Answer (score 1):

You can set the youtube thumbnail from Youtube itself, no need (or possible?) to set it via ffmpeg. More info on how to do this can be found here: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/72431?hl=en

Comment: in the first 5 seconds of the video it has my thumbnail or logo this does not show up as thumbnail when uploading video and it ends up selecting randomly on youtube